# Сортировка чисел с разделителями в текстовом поле

Tags: sql-server, сортировка

Исходные данные:

- MS SQl server
- Таблица с иерархическими данными, связи в которой обеспечены двумя полями: id и id_parent.

id_parent содержит id родителя.

Есть текстовое поле, где хранятся порядковые номера вида "1.1.2.3.".
Вопрос в том как отсортировать таблицу по возрастанию этих номеров, если они воспринимаются как текст.

**Пример**

НЕПРАВИЛЬНО:

```
1.
1.1.
10.1.
2.1.
```

ПРАВИЛЬНО

```
1.
1.1.
1.1.1.
2.1.
...
10.1.
10.2.
```

Рекурсивный запрос по 12тыс. строк выполняется более 5 минут и как действующее решение не подходит

Comment: Можно номер в _hierarhyid_ сконвертировать, напр. `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('1.'), ('1.1.'), ('10.1.'), ('2.1.')) t(n) ORDER BY CAST('/' + REPLACE(t.n, '.', '/') AS hierarchyid)`

Comment: Спасибо! 
Это то что надо.

**select Long_Number, * 
from myTable order by cast('/'+replace(Long_Number, '.', '/') as hierarchyid)** - даже не знал что там такое есть